# Linux: Is it safe to have Tor run by the www-data user?

Tags: linux

I am running Tor via a PHP `exec()` and therefore its instance and data directory will be owned by 'www-data'. Is this OK to do or is there a better way I should be doing this?

Answer (score 2):

Supposing you're hosting other sites under the `www-data` user, it is not a very safe configuration.
I'd suggest you deploy the PHP site via [FastCGI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FastCGI) so that it runs under a dedicated user account. You can also consider using `sudo` to launch the external command under different user (you'll need to configure `/etc/sudoers` with `NOPASSWD` switch for this particular command).